# Protractor safari redirect

Tags: safari, protractor, safaridriver

I'm having trouble with safariDriver running tests with Protractor. 
everything works fine on chrome and phantom.

so the problem is lets say i have a page i click on a link and it reroutes me to another page where it does something and then routes me back to where i was going.

so in chrome i do click on link and then get the url.  url === expected url.

in safari though

click on link get url   url === rerouted url and hasn't reached where i was going yet. i've tried doing browser.wait(function(){ return browser.getCurrentUrl}) doesn't work.

heres a snippet.

```
waitAndGetUrl: function(){
  return  browser.wait(function(){
        return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url){
                 return url 
               });
    }, 1000)
}

describe("should click on link and add cookie", function(){
    it('click the fragment link', function(){
        testPageActions.clickOnFragmentLink();
        expect(testPageActions.waitAndGetUrl()).toContain(fragmentPath);
    });

    it('should grab have the cookie set', function(){
        expect(testPageActions.getCookie()).toBe(Cookie);
    });
```

});

ps i tried doing browser.sleep() as well

Answer (score 1):

I think your own answer isn't correct.

1. Sleep doesn't have a `function`, see the [docs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.sleep). I think it will now work because you are just waiting 1 second.
2. Secondly you are using an `expect` in the comparison. When an `expect` fails it will reject a promise and will kill you test for the wrong reason.

With you initial question and code you almost had the answer. You only need to implement it like this

```
waitAndGetUrl: function(expectedUrl){    
    return browser.wait(function(){
        return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(currentUrl){
            return expectedUrl === currentUrl;
        });
    }, 3000);
}
```

The `wait` waits for a condition to become `true`. In this case you want to wait until the `currentUrl` is equal to the `expectedUrl`. If not it will executed the `getCurrentUrl()` for the max timeout you have given to become `true`. If the max timeout you gave is over it will fail. See the [docs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) for more information and adding a custom timeout message.

Comment: After reading your comment i went back and ran the test with a failing test and still passed so you are right.
i went back and used the .wait and everything works great

Answer (score 0):

We need to know the output/error you are getting to help better, but try resolving the promise:

```
it('click the fragment link', function(){
    testPageActions.clickOnFragmentLink();
    testPageActions.waitAndGetUrl().then(function(url) {
        expect(url).toContain(fragmentPath);
    };
});
```

And if `clickOnFragmentLink()` returns a promise, you must do the same thing there also.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that
so when we click on a link we have a script that takes a user to our site and then brings them back to where they we're going. when i do get the url its still stuck in our address and not the where they we're going. 
so  google.com/  ---> oursite.com/ ----> google.com/search?whatever
in chrome get url gives me google.com/search?whatever
safari gives me oursite.com/

i'll try your solution though

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `expect(testPageActions.waitAndGetUrl()).to.eventually.be(fragmentPath);`

Comment: I've tried this. looks like my version of jasmine doesn't know what .to.eventually.be means. 

i guess i will test a bunch of things and see if i can come up with more information.

Answer (score -1):

Hey guys thanks you guys gave me good ideas. 
Basically used the first answer but used .sleep instead of wait

```
describe("should click on link and add cookie", function(){
    it('click the fragment link', function(){
        var link = element(by.css(fragmentLinkCss));
        link.click().then(function(){
            browser.sleep(function(){
                browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url){
                    expect(url).toContain(fragmentPath);
                })
            }, 1000)
        });
    });

    it('should grab have the cookie set', function(){
        expect(testPageActions.getCookie()).toBe(Cookie);
    });
});
```

Comment: Downvoted this because of incorrect code implementation, see my answer for the docs and a correct answer

Comment: Thanks for this. Mind if you give the exact link to your solution ?

Comment: What do you mean? The answer / I mentioned is above